# Allowing apache to access multiple volumes under AWS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mount

I've added another volume to my EC2 instance (mounted as /dev/xvdf), and I need to be able to place files on that volume and be able to retrieve them via the /var/www/ directory. How can I accomplish this? This is an Ubuntu instance, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest scenario may be to configure a partition on that block device, then to create a filesystem on it and finally to attach or so-called mount it at some directory.

1. create a primary partition number 1 (follow the help) - `sudo fdisk /dev/xvdf`
2. create an ext4 filesystem - `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdf1`
3. create a mountpoint - `sudo mkdir /foo`
4. mount the filesystem - `sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /foo`

If you wish you can mount it under `/var/www` directory as you asked. If you don't want to mount it there then configure another Apache2 `VirtualHost` with `DocumentRoot` pointing there. with To make the step 4 persistent, append this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/xvdf1       /foo         auto    defaults        0       0
```

Finally, just google such kind of tasks and I'm sure you will find more detailed documentation how to do it as this is one of the most basic administration tasks.